# Zellig Harris and the alphabet

Tags: reference-request, writing-systems, writing, history-of-linguistics

I would be very interested if someone could provide me with a useful link to read Zellig Harris's text on the origin of the alphabet. The reference is:

Harris, Zellig S. 1933. “Acrophony and vowellessness in the creation of the alphabet”. Journal of American Oriental Society 53.387. [Summary of 1932 Univ. of Pennsylvania M.A. thesis “Origin of the Alphabet”.]

I have not been able to find it, and since I am writing from Iberia at this moment, in site access to any US library is out of the question at this point in time for me.

Comment: Two copies are known to exist, at MIT and U. Penn; it is non-circulating at Penn.

Answer (score 3):

The journal you are looking for can be easily read online on JSTOR. Here is the link to the page of your interest:

http://www.jstor.org/stable/594233?seq=22#page_scan_tab_contents

However, it's really just 4 lines abstract of Harris' paper. I don't think it's more useful than Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks @Artemij Keidan. I will have a look at it. However, ist it possible to have access to the original long text by Harris?

Answer (score 1):

1933 Acrophony and vowellessness in the creation of the alphabet. J. Am. Orient. Soc. 53:387.

This is the sum total of the notice in the JAOS. He does not seem to have published it as an article:

> Mr. ZELLIG S. HARRIS, of the University of Pennsylvania: Acrophony and
>   Vowellessness in the creation of the Alphabet. Remarks by Professor 
>   Albright.
>   The existence of the acrophonic principle in the alphabet
>   is shown  by the Serabit material. Vowellessness is explained from
>   acrophony.  In Semitic no word begins with a vowel: no sign therefore
>   came to  receive a vowel as its value.

Comment: Well, it was his master thesis, so I guess It must have amounted to 80-100 pages and I guess it should be stocked at some University Libraty, maybe at Penn.....

Comment: standing to his bibliography the thesis has never been published
http://zelligharris.org/ZSHbibliography.html